# mongodb geoNear + additional filters?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

Is it possible to add more filters when using geoNear in mongodb? For example, say I my records look like the following:

```
{
 _id: {},
 cid: 1,
 latlon: [ -74.07096147537231, 40.9088747684256 ]
}
```

Can I pass "cid" to be sure that only the records with a "cid" that equals "1"? If it is not possible with geoNear, how would I do this? I am using geoNear because it returns the distance...

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, sure it's possible. You can use any filtering with $near as usual:

```
db.places.find( { latlon: { $near : [50,50] } }, {cid: 1} )
```

**Update:**

If you need distance use `db.runCommand`, if no need distance -- `db.collection.find` as usual.

From [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand):

> The geoNear command has the added
>   benefit of returning the distance of
>   each item from the specified point in
>   the results, as well as some
>   diagnostics for troubleshooting.

There is `query` parameter in `db.runCommand`, you can use it like this:

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear : "latlon" , near : [ 50 , 50 ], num : 10,
                 query : { cid: 1 } } );
```

Comment: but I'm using something like: db.runCommand({ geoNear : "locs", near : [0, 0], spherical : true, maxDistance : range / earthRadius }); If I use db.example.find(); how will I calculate the distance?

Comment: I found this "query:" option after posting yesterday! But I'm going to mark it as answered for the help! Thanks, so much!

Comment: How do I specify what keys to project? For examples, in this case, whay if I only wanted to get _id back... Thanks!